Can't pass recordset variable to report parameter and utilize DoCmd.OpenReport
I'm trying to get an Access report to run in VBA by passing a variable from a recordset to the report using DoCmd.OpenReport but can't get it to work.  Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?
Using the specific assigned variable in the underlying report named “Code”
with specific text works:  "[Code]=""LXFT48"""
But when I try to pass the corresponding recordset variable which is “FactCode”
nothing is displayed in the report: "[Code]=" & "[FactCode]"
Instead I’m asked for the parameter’s value so evidently it cannot identify the field.
I tried substitutions for [FactCode] like [Model] and rst![Model] but can’t get anything to work.
Is it just a matter of getting the quotes right?
I can get the recordset data to display for each record via msgbox.
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim FactCode As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tbl TRAAFES-1")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tbl TRAAFES-1]"
Set rst = tdf.OpenRecordset()

With rst
    rst.MoveFirst

    Do Until .EOF
    FactCode = rst![Model]
      
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt Pricing Rules- AAFES Format - FULL REPORT", acViewPreview, "", "Code =         ""LXFT48””", acNormal ‘ *** THIS WORKS ***

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt Pricing Rules- AAFES Format - FULL REPORT", acViewPreview, "", "[Code]=" & "[FactCode]", acNormal ‘ *** DOESN’T WORK***


To fix your code use "[Code]=" & rst![FactMode] not "[Code]=[FactMode]" To summarize, you re building the string you want using concatenation.
This is essentially the same as the difference between these two statements:
Dim name as String
Dim greeting as String

name = "David"
greeting = "Hello, name!"           '// Hello, name! <-- incorrect
greeting = "Hello, " & name & "!"   '// Hello, David!

Your code is a little more complex because you are building a string that needs to be evaluated by Access as a filter criteria. You have a variable FactCode that has a value such as LXFT48 and you want to build a string [Code] = LXFt48 .. but this is wrong! You need to build a string [Code] = 'LXFT48'!
So in this case also add the quotes around your string.
Example:
Dim myStr as String
dim FactCode as String
FactCode = "LXFT48"
myStr = "[Code] = " & "'" & FactCode & "'"

'// Or if you prefer a few less characters to type
myStr = "[Code] = '" & FactCode & "'"


Thank you for so quick a reply!  I have the variable "FactCode" already equial to the recordset field "Model."  So whether I use "[Code=" & [FactCode] or "[Code=" & rst![Model] I run into the same problem where the report doesn't look for the value in the field [Model] but rather takes the value in the field and treats it as its own variable asking for input.: 'Enter Parameter Value' for field LXFT48. Something else is going on beside my missing ampersand.  Whatever insight you can give is greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time.

Typo: I meant "[Code]=' in both cases (brackets on both sides)

I think your second problem is that FactCode is a string. So it should be "[Code]=" & "'" &  rst![FactCode] & "'" - strings need quotes around them in code.

I tried all suggestions and a myriad of other combinations and still come up with the same issue.  I've since switched to a form and since there's a limited number of final outputs, I've just put in a statement for each output.  It's not really the way to do things, but it works.  Thanks, everyone for you input, though.  It's great to have people willing to lend a hand. Thanks again.
